# Origin of inheritance in programming languages

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

What was the first language to support inheritance? Was code re-use the design intent of the feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming history and not a problem currently being experienced. I'm pretty sure a web search along the lines of "history of object oriented programming" could find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first object oriented language was [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula). Specifically Simula67, introduced in 1967 and implemented in 1968. Simula67 added the concept of classes and subclasses (inheritance) inspired by a research paper (theory, not any specific language) by C.A.R. Hoare describing the concept of classes as a collection of data in memory published in 1966.

So the first o-o language was Simula67 and inheritance was introduced in Simula67. It was there from the beginning.

Now, the real interesting question would be what was the first o-o language to abandon inheritance. Go is one o-o language that intentionally left out inheritance. But that is a very modern example.